# PyQt6 How to get Tableview header name/text from item on click

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt6

I've got a gui app in PyQt6 that just has a button and table view in it. Once pressed, the button connects `TableModel`, which inherits from `QtCore.QAbstractTableModel`, to the table view populates the data a does a bit of formatting. Great.

What I now want is to be able to access the header names (just the text thats in the headers), when a cell in the table is clicked. I've successfully connected a function that just prints out `item.row()` and `item.column()` and this is functioning correctly. I can't for the life of me get the header info though. Any help would be great

**Code so far**

I'm just posting the most relevant parts of the code, as it's long and spread over multiple files. Just lmk if there's more you need to see.

```
class PrimaryWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    """docstring for PrimaryWindow"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.dbloc=r'test.sqlite'
        self.conn=sqlite3.connect(self.dbloc)

        #do all the connections
        self.ui.DataButton.clicked.connect(self.get_data)
        self.ui.DataTable.clicked.connect(self.Get_new_view)

    def get_data(self):
        #get some data from db
     
        self.tmodel = TableModel(self.data)
        self.ui.DataTable.setModel(self.tmodel)

    def Get_new_view(self, item):
        print('clicked',item.row(),item.column())


class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):

        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.BackgroundRole:
            colors={
            20:'#da172e', #red
            15:'#ede60b', #yellow
            10:'#0bed10', #green
            99:'#0b6ded', #blue
            5: '#FFFFFF' #white
            }
            value = self._data.iloc[index.row(),index.column()]
            if value == 0:
                return #don't color 0 values
            else:
                return QtGui.QColor(colors[max(i for i in colors if i<=value)]) #returns threshold value as key to color dict, sends string of hex color code

        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            # See below for the nested-list data structure.
            # .row() indexes into the outer list,
            # .column() indexes into the sub-list
            return str(self._data.iloc[index.row(),index.column()])

    def rowCount(self, index):
        # The length of the outer list.
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        # The following takes the first sub-list, and returns
        # the length (only works if all rows are an equal length
        return len(self._data.columns)

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        # section is the index of the column/row.
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Orientation.Horizontal:
                return str(self._data.columns[section])

            if orientation == Qt.Orientation.Vertical:
                return str(self._data.index[section])

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable|Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled|Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEditable
```

Comment: `print(self.tmodel.headerData(item.column(), Qt.Horizontal, Qt.DisplayRole))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but when i tried that I got this error `AttributeError: type object 'Qt' has no attribute 'Horizontal'`

Comment: PyQt6 uses full enum names, so it's `Qt.Orientation.Horizontal`. Whenever in doubt, always look for the documentation. In this case, look up the [Qt namespace](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html).

Comment: You're right, that did the trick. Wow thanks a lot. Post this as an answer and i'll gladly accept.

Comment: It's probably because i'm a python pleb and don't speak C but the documentation for Qt is terrible to use. Compared to the docs for something like pandas it's not even close.

Comment: It's just a matter of habit. There's practically no difference between the C++ API and the PySide/PyQt bindings (except for an incredibly small portion of functions, due to the way python uses references). On the left of the function you have the returned type (`void` means that the function returns `None`), the arguments are listed with internal types that can be easily considered for their python counterparts (thanks to the automatic conversion of the binding) unless they are specific Qt classes. In fact, the Qt docs are *extremely* well written, and I've never typed a single line of C++.

Comment: Totally agree about the high quality of the Qt docs. The language differences are largely irrelevant when reading the descriptive text, and the logic of the code examples always translates easily into PyQt/PySide. I have almost no C++ experience, but have always much preferred using the original docs. I've also spent quite a lot of time reading the Qt source code, and have never found my lack of C++ to be any barrier there either. I am entirely self-taught and have pretty average abilities as a programmer, so I think that in itself proves just how good all these libraries and their docs are.

Comment: @SuperStew I can only agree again with ekhumoro, and even more: as soon as I began to dig into the sources, a "whole new world" opened to my eyes, and that's also thanks to code that, just like the docs, is generally well written: even if C++ styling is less strict than Python (i.e.: indentation), they share lots of aspects, and Qt code guidelines are quite specific about styling. As many, I was firstly amazed by it, then I got scared. Then I tried to switch to Gtk, and I **really** regretted it. Take your time, don't rush it. It's worth it, and you'll never end learning ('cause it's fun!) :)